# iOS - Get Address around a Long/Lat

Tags: iphone, ios, geocoding

I was wondering if anyone knew how to get a list of addresses around a longitude and latitude?

I've been using the following code but it always yields one address:

```
[self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: currentLocation  completionHandler:
 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
     for (int i = 0; i < placemarks.count; i++)
     {
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:i];
         if (placemark.addressDictionary != nil)
         {
             Location *aLocation = [[Location alloc] init];
             aLocation.locationName = [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"Name"];
             aLocation.locationAddress = [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"City"];
             aLocation.currentLocation = placemark.location;
             [self.tableData addObject:aLocation];
         }
     }
    [self.locationsTableView reloadData];
 }];
```

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158557/get-street-address-at-lat-long-pair

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557026/can-you-create-an-annotation-in-mapview-from-an-address/13564318#13564318

Comment: What kind of addresses are you looking for?  Do you want all mailing addresses or just specific landmarks (places)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if Core Location's geocoded is intended to do that.

Google allows for this kind of search but with limits with their Places API. That being said, you can do a search for something like "Pizza" and get results within a radius.

For more info look at: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

You can use their API to query based on a lat/long with a search query and radius to get results looking like what you're after.

Good luck!

Comment: Do you know if it will give me X number of locations based on the long/lat I provide?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the point. You'll have to read the documentation but you can limit how many locations are returned if need be.

Answer (score 0):

First change  your latitude and longitude value (*and check may be your code is right*) becoze in map, some coordinate does not provide full information.

following provide code for if some coordinate does not provide full information then how can give you condition for get specific CITY(*or other Infor*) name.
Here `getReverseGeocode`  method call by `[self getReverseGeocode];`

```
- (void) getReverseGeocode
    {
        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

        if(currentLatLong.count > 0)
        {
            CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoOrdinate;

            myCoOrdinate.latitude = LatValue;
            myCoOrdinate.longitude = LangValue;

            CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:myCoOrdinate.latitude longitude:myCoOrdinate.longitude];
            [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
             {
                 if (error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"failed with error: %@", error);
                     return;
                 }
                 if(placemarks.count > 0)
                 {
                     NSString *MyAddress = @"";
                     NSString *city = @"";

                     if([placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] != NULL)
                         MyAddress = [[placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
                     else
                         MyAddress = @"Address Not founded";

                     if([placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"SubAdministrativeArea"] != NULL)
                         city = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"SubAdministrativeArea"];
                     else if([placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"City"] != NULL)
                         city = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"City"];
                     else if([placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"Country"] != NULL)
                         city = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"Country"];
                     else
                         city = @"City Not founded";

                   NSLog(@"%@",city);
                   NSLog(@"%@", MyAddress);
                 }
             }];
        }
    }
```